# Is it true that $\nabla_x \int_0^\infty f(t,0) dt = 0 \implies \nabla_x f(t,0) = 0 \ \forall t>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ and $F(x) = \int_0^\infty f(t,x) dt$. If $\nabla_x F(0) = 0$ do we have that $\nabla_x f(t,0) = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb R_+$? If not, which assumptions do we need to have to make it true?

Comment: Can you find a function $f(t,x)$ with real $x$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(t,x) dt$ does not depend on $x$?

Comment: @HansEngler What do you mean?

Comment: Find any function $f_0$ such that $\int_0^\infty f_0(x) dx = 1$. Then set $f(x,t) = x f_0(xt)$ for $x > 0$. Compute $\int_0^\infty f(x,t) dt$ using change of variables.